# How to keep RDD persisted and consistent?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following code (simplification for a complex situation):

```
val newRDD = prevRDD.flatMap{a =>
    Array.fill[Int](scala.util.Random.nextInt(10)){scala.util.Random.nextInt(2)})
}.persist()
val a = newRDD.count
val b = newRDD.count
```

and even that the RDD supposed to be persisted (and therefore consistent), `a` and `b` are not identical in most cases.

Is there a way to keep the results of the first action consistent, so when the second "action" will be called, the results of the first action will be returned?

*** Edit ***

The issue that I have is apparently caused by `zipWithIndex` method exists in my code - which creates indices higher than the count. I'll ask about it in a different thread. Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, a and b are identical in my tests

Comment: as the RDD is persisted it should be consistent. a and b both should have same value. I suppose you are trying to do some other operations.Please provide your detailed piece of code

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make sure 100% consistent.

When you call `persist` it will try to cache all of partitions on memory if it fits.
Otherwise, It will recompute partitions which are not fit on memory.

Comment: That is what I thought, and it makes a lot of sense.

Can it also happen on `zipWithIndex` in rdd (or `row_number` in DataFrame) - so that later call will be different from the earlier call (and so I can't count on "id" column to be consistent)?

Comment: It depends on your code & logic. 
Let's say your `prevRDD` is immutable ( for example: it loads data from a static - unchanged file)
In your case, the count value `a` and `b` will be the same. 
But it's not guaranteed that your rdd will have the same data due to your data is obtained from a random logic at `flatMap`